# Get position of object after sort in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I developing a web application and I'm using MongoDB to store data. I am able to sort the data and display it properly, but I want to get the position of the object after sorting it with Mongo. So far I have this code:

`Websites.find({_id: {$lte: website_id}}, {sort:{upvotes: -1}}).count();`

It doesn't quite work. It returns sort of position but not related to the `sort:{upvotes: -1}`.

So, the question is, how can I return `1` to the most upvoted, `2` to the second, and so on?

Comment: Not too sure about returning indexes, but I'm pretty sure you can use [Cursor])https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Seems to be okay what you're doing. I'd try do: `Websites.find({_id: {$lte: website_id}}, {sort:{upvotes: -1}}).fetch()` to debug this.

Comment: Why is there a count() method there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do that.

```
<template name="websites">
  <h2>My Websites list</h2>
  <div class="row">
    {{#each websites}}
      Index:{{@index}}
      Feild1:{{feild1}}
      Feild2:{{feild1}}
      ...
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.websites.helpers({
  websites: function () {
    return Websites.find({_id: {$lte: website_id}}, {sort:{upvotes: -1}});
  },
  index: function (index) {
    return ++index;
  },
})
```

I didn't create any table or list but as per your requirement you can add that as well.
I hope hay will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Websites.find({_id: {$lte: website_id}}, {sort:{upvotes: -1}}).fetch()
```

Comment: Just code is not generally a good answer - try adding an explanation of why you think this will solve the problem.